# Can MS Office or OpenOffice.org open Pages documents from an iPad?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, ipad, cross-platform, iwork-pages

Can MS Office or OpenOffice.org open Pages documents from an iPad?

Comment: If you have an iPad, why don't you just try it? :D

Comment: Maybe the asker doesn't want to buy Pages without knowing how useful it is. Or maybe the asker wants to know whether they can send Pages documents to their Windows-using associates.

Comment: I hope to buy an iPad this week. I'm considering my options here.

Comment: ah. I see now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Apple Support Technote](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4065), Pages for iPad does support export to Microsoft Word 97 or later.

Opening the Pages documents directly, though, is an unlikely proposition.

This [MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/151397/2010/05/word_ipad.html) outlines the limitations of editing MS Word documents on the iPad.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about OpenOffice, but unfortunately Office cannot open Pages documents.

ETA: after a fair amount of Googling, it's safe to say that OpenOffice can't open Pages documents either.

Comment: What does ETA stand for?

Comment: I'm thinking "Edited To Add" but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Ya, "Edited to Add"..  It's an old message board acronym..

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is using the [**Office Web Apps**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/web-apps/) on the iPad, which would allow to create and edit Office format files stored on [**Windows Live SkyDrive**](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-skydrive).

Comment: This works best with a 3G enabled iPad. Not everyone has that.

Comment: @Moshe: I spend 90% of my day in areas which have wifi, and I hardly ever need to use 3G on my laptop or smartphone.